# objects are not valid as a react child (found object with keys) while passing props from one component to other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a particular selected URL(data) from a component (List.js) to a component (DD.js), DD.js has two components, Left and Right, I want to display data in the Left component so have passed the props to left component, but I get the error saying

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {url})

. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

DD.js

```
export default class DD extends Component {
  render(){
    let data = this.props.location.state
    return(
      <div className="dd-wrapper">
        <div className="left-drawer-wrapper">
          <Left url={data}/>
        </div>
        {/*right side section*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Left.js

```
export default class Left extends Component{
  render(){
    let url = this.props.url
    return(
      <div>
        {url}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

List.js

```
<tbody>
 {
   this.state.urls.map( (list,i) => {
   return(
     <tr key={i}>
       <td>
        <Link to={{pathname:`/service/${this.service_name}/requests`,
                        state:{url:this.state.urls[i]}}}
                        onClick={()=>this.selectedUrlHandler(i)}>{list} 
        </Link>
       </td>
       <td>{this.service_name}</td>
      </tr>
     );
   })
  }
</tbody>
```

I get the requested answer when i do console.log(url) , but when i remove it and do just {url} , the error occures , not sure what is going wrong .

Comment: Most probably `this.props.location.state` is an object, which is why you get that error

Comment: Could you show the List.js file?

Comment: Probably you are rendering object in such way: `{obj} `. Try to decompose it manually like `{obj.value}` (it depends on the object structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not render an object as a children of a node in react component. To do so, you can stringify the object i.e.

```
export default class Left extends Component{
 render(){
  let url = this.props.url
  return(
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(url)}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

OR

You can render a particular value at a time from the object.

```
export default class Left extends Component{
 render(){
  let url = this.props.url
  return(
    <div>
      {url.url1}
      {url.url2}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the url is passed an an object to the `Left` component which tried to render it you get an error. Instead just render the particular property of the `state` object like

```
export default class DD extends Component {
  render(){
    let data = this.props.location.state
    return(
      <div className="dd-wrapper">
        <div className="left-drawer-wrapper">
          <Left url={data}/>
        </div>
        {/*right side section*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
export default class Left extends Component{
  render(){
    let url = this.props.url.value
    return(
      <div>
        {url}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried your snippet , but nothing is getting rendered , its empty , But when i do console.log , i get undefined .

Answer (score 0):

The url is not a string it is an Object and react can not render Objects in JSX. You can check that by converting that to string.

```
<Left url={JSON.stringify(data)} />
```

Comment: That's not true. React accepts and handles objects in props.

Comment: yes have tried that , i get the entire object as a string , but i need just the value part of the object.

Comment: Show which key you wanted to show in the parent component like
{url.key}

Comment: Yes you can send objects in props but  I said it can not render objects directly in JSX. you need to print the value of some key. @Valdimir Serykh

Comment: @Uday - Yes when i do {obj.key} more like url.url (the solution which i needed) i get the data ,                                                                                                         
 Also Is it not  possible to render that entire object ?

Comment: No , react does not allow you to render objects. You can make an array of the objects and loop over to show data. @nishant

Comment: Okay ,got it , Thank you